# jQuery Attribute Usage for Target

Tags: jquery

Can anyone see why the following code is not causing my url top open up in a new window, i.e:

```
        $(location).attr({
            href: toLoad,
            target: "_blank"
        });
```

where toLoad is my url.

Looking at the view source, all seems fine and basically looks like:

```
<a target="_blank" title="" href="http://......etc">ccc</a>
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You want it to immediately open, or when clicked?

Comment: Seems a little unclear, you want it to open a new window? and - close thise one? or just open a new one?  And, when is this action to take place, on the click of the link or something else, or on the page open?

Comment: Want it to open when clicked into a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery wrapper is used for DOM elements, not arbitrary objects, and `location` (`window.location`) doesn't even have a `target` attribute. Simply do a `window.open(...)`.